# Python: How can I get all the content from a textbox in a form (cgi script)? form.getvalue("textBoxName") only gets me the first word/letter?

Tags: python, html, cgi

So my code looks something like this:

> form = cgi.FieldStorage( )
>
> question1= form.getvalue( "question1" )
>
> print question1

The problem is, only the first word of question1 textbox is printed.

I figured out why I wasn't getting the full value. I'm an idiot and was printing it out to an . I switched to   and it works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question sounds interesting, but there just isn't enough information in the question. Please reduce your CGI program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates your problem. copy-paste that entire, small, program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.org for more info. You might also tell us what environment is running your script: what web server, which version of Python, what operating system.

Comment: Advice: Don't use CGI it's slow and bloated, you may prefer using HTTP from end to end. Typically try Cherrypy. It will be easier to test (no need of a webserver to be tested) and easy to configure server side (tell your HTTP server to "proxy" to your application).